# adding list values into a worksheet column

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to insert the values from a list into a specific column from a worksheet using the `openpyxl` library in Python:

```
list_A=[1,2,3,4,5]

for i in range(1,5):
    for j in range(5):
        (sheet.cell(row=i,column=1)).value=list_A[j]
```

but it only adds the last value of the list (5) at each `i` row

any advice on that?

Answer (score 2):

For a fixed `i` inside the first `for-loop` you overwrite the value (`j`-times) from `list_A` in the cell: `i-th row`, `1st column`.